# How to push a form above the keyboard?

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

I have a form that gets visible when a button is clicked. I also have multiple input tags inside that form. When I type data on to the first input, it is visible but 2nd and 3rd input tags get hidden under the keyboard.

```
<div class="showmodal" *ngIf="formDisplay">
    <div class="containdiv">
        <ion-row class="milkColor">
            <ion-label style="padding-left: 5%;">Add New Contact </ion-label>
            <ion-icon class="iconPad" name="close"  (click)="cancel()" > </ion-icon>
        </ion-row>
        <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm(form)" novalidate>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-label text-right> <b>Name :</b> </ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-input [value]="name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" type="text" placeholder="Contact Name" required></ion-input>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-label text-right> <b>Occupation :</b> </ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                        <ion-input [value]="service" name="service" [(ngModel)]="service" type="text" placeholder="Occupation" required></ion-input>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-label text-right > <b>Contact No. :</b> </ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-input [value]="number" name="number" [(ngModel)]="number" type="number" placeholder="Number" required></ion-input>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row >
                <ion-col text-center>
                    <button [disabled]=!form.valid  class="textLower" ion-button type="submit" value="Submit" >Submit</button>                  
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my css

```
 .showmodal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.2);
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0px;
}    
.showmodal .containdiv {
    background: white;
    margin-top:52%;
    min-height:30%;
    overflow:auto;
    margin: 150px 20px 0 17px;
}
```

I need all 3 inputs to be visible when that form arrives, and if I have more than 3 input tags, I should able to scroll the list of inputs

Can someone help me??

Comment: Would putting     window.scrollBy(0, 300) on button click help?

Comment: could you give me some sample how to do that

Answer (score 0):

On the button (click) event where you set `formDisplay` to `true` to show the form, add `scroll` so the form content will go up a little and the inputs will show up higher on the screen and not hidden by the keyboard.
Something as the following:

**HTML**

```
<button ....(click)="displayForm()"...>Display Form</form>
```

**Typescript**

```
displayForm(){
...
 this.displayForm=true; 
 window.scroll(0, 100); // or an other number of pixels enough to display
...
}
```

Comment: Do you have position: fixed on that div?

Comment: try scrollBy(100,100) please

Comment: Is there enough space for the other inputs to be visible? The keyboard height is fixed, so the rest should be enough for all three inputs to be shown